# Permission denied (publickey) CloudControl

Tags: git, cloudcontrol

I always get this error with cloudcontrol. Help.
Using Windows with Git installed.

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists. Command '['C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe',
>   'push', u'ssh://phpapiya sh@cloudcontrolled.com/repository.git',
>   'master']' returned non-zero exit status  128

Comment: You can't push to the repository.  Are you ***certain*** that you can?

Comment: Yes I am certain that I can.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your public key to cloudControl? If not, please do this:

```
cctrluser key.add
```

For full context please visit our [documentation](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/platform-documentation#keys).